# How to add itens to the beginning of a Sencha Touch 2 List after loading a previousPage using a store?

Tags: list, pagination, sencha-touch-2, store

I have a really big list of itens which I'd like to display in a mobile app using sencha touch. The list is paginated and the user can start viewing from any page. Sencha Touch 2 has a really good paginated store and the list has a ListPaging plugin which helps to load new itens at the end of the item. I'm trying to adapt this plugin so I can load itens from previous pages. The problem is: after I reload the store with the previous page, if I have the  'clearOnPageLoad' config option set to false, the new itens are appended to the list instead of put at the beginning. I can't find any way to change this behaviour. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi.Am facing the same issue. Could you share your code. Might help me with mine.

Comment: I answered my own question, maybe just sorting your store is enough for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the Store.js code a little, I now understand what happens: the call to previousPage is just a call to loadPage(currentPage - 1), and it only change the parameters of the ajax call, so the data refresh can't know if the new data should be put before or after the current page.

The method "doDataRefresh" is the one internally called when you update your store. If addRecords is set to false, this method clears the internal array of data when loading new data. If its set to true, it will just add data to the end:

```
        ... (internals of doDataRefresh)
        if (operation.getAddRecords() !== true) {
        for (i = 0; i < ln; i++) {
            record = currentRecords[i];
            record.unjoin(me);

            // If the record we are removing is not part of the records we are about to add to the store then handle
            // the destroying or removing of the record to avoid memory leaks.
            if (records.indexOf(record) === -1) {
                if (syncRemovedRecords && record.phantom !== true) {
                    removed.push(record);
                }
                else if (destroyRemovedRecords && !syncRemovedRecords && !record.stores.length) {
                    record.destroy();
                }
            }
        }
        data.clear();
        // This means we have to fire a clear event though
        me.fireEvent('clear', me);
    }

    if (records && records.length) {
        // Now lets add the records without firing an addrecords event
        me.suspendEvents();
        me.add(records);
        me.resumeEvents();
    }
```

To completely solve this problem, you could override the store methods so that:

- A call to "previousPage" keeps track of the fact that the new data should be put before the current data
- Change the doDataRefresh so that it decides based on a flag if it should add the new data before or after the current store items.

However, I ended up just sorting the store - it was enough for my usecase.